# Why can't I get Windows 10 Hyper-V VM to connect to the internet/network?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I am running Hyper-V on a Windows 10 system (host).
I have a Windows 10 VM I am connecting to.

I am having difficulties connecting the VM to the internet and my local network.
I have created a new Virtual Switch in Hyper-V as follows:
[image: Virtual Switch]

**I have assigned the virtual switch to my VM as follows:**
[image: VM - Virtual Switch]

**In the VM I see I have no internet connection available.**
[image: No Internet Connection]

**I opened Network and Connection Settings.**
[image: No Internet in Connection Settings]

**This is what I see in Connection Settings:**

[image: No Internet]

**When I click on either entry, I see the following:**
[image: Connection Options]

I can't figure out how to get this VM connected to the host machine/local network/internet.
I've googled and tried several different approaches (PowerShell).
Shouldn't I have the option to set between a "**Public**" and "**Private**" connection?
This does not show up in Windows 10.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I get this to work correctly?

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: I would have thought that would work.  Only two things I can suggest:  Why is that switch also connected to the "legacy network adapter" in your VM - in fact, _why_ do you have a  "legacy network adapter" in your VM?  Second (this is a dumb suggestion, yet possible): Does your computer have >1 external network port and if so, did you connect your new virtual switch to the right one? (I.e., the one that has the network cable hanging out of it ...)

Answer (score -1):

I was using the incorrect external network connection type in the Virtual Switch Manager. I was using Ethernet instead of the WiFi.